# iOS system sound service unable to adjust volume

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, audio, audiotoolbox

in .h:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    SystemSoundID beatAudio;
}
```

in.m:

```
//File path already created
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &(beatAudio));
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(beatAudio);
```

The sound is perfect, but when I toggle up and down the volume bar, the volume of this sound is not affected. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created it as a system sound, and in order for them to be affected by the volume control, you have to change the phone settings

Go into settings->sounds and select 'Change with Buttons' to on.

You may not need to play this sound as a system sound though ?